# How to answer in users language using Pyrogram?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I am working on the Telegram auto-replies bot, it's expected to answer in different languages. But I can't find a way how to get users' language code to activate the required scenario. At least there is no `language_code` in get_users(), so I am disappointed about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telegram usually sends a `language_code` in the `Message.from_user` you receive. You could use that to handle the languages.

Alternatively, you could use a library like [plate](https://github.com/delivrance/plate) and just ask your users for their language.
I actually made an example on how that could work: https://github.com/ColinShark/pyrogram-language-chooser

Comment: Still receiving `None` using `Message.from_user`, but plate seems like a good alternative, thank you

Comment: I found out the reason for my problem. I'm using pyrogram with a default user account, but if I use it with a bot account, it allows me to get `language_code` for some reason.

Comment: @s1ckoleg Your term "bot" in your initial questions implies you're using an actual bot. If you're talking about a userbot, an automated script that runs on your account, of course you'll get different results. Please be more specific in the future.